# Работа с SVN

Tags: svn, сервер

Создал пользователя
htpasswd /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd user_name

Создал репозиторий
svnadmin create /var/www/svn/repo_name

SVN доступен по ссылке http://site.com/svn/repo_name

А как с ним дальше работать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Устанавливаешь себе программу [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) заходишь в любой папке на компьютере в контекстное меню (меню правой кнопки мыши) -> Tortoise SVN -> Repo Browser. Указываешь путь к своему репозиторию, и можешь создавать в нём папки, файлы. Делать чекауты, апдейты и коммиты. Можно создать пустую папку в репозитории, затем сделать её чекаут в локальную папку. В ней развернуть проект с сделать коммит. Все новые файлы добавить в репозиторий.
Это в 3 словах, а так советую курить мануалы :-)

Comment: Благодарю. Главное хоть какой клиент было услышать)